# How can I decrypt an encrypted text

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I got the following code from https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-crypto-module-a-tutorial . When I `/encrypt` and `/decrypt` the result, I get the following error while decrypting:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:141:29)
    at Decipheriv.prefinish (internal/streams/transform.js:147:10)
```

The code is:

```
app.post("/encrypt", (req, res) => {
  crypto.scrypt(password, "salt", 24, (err, key) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    crypto.randomFill(new Uint8Array(16), (err, iv) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
      let encrypted = "";
      cipher.setEncoding("hex");
      cipher.on("data", (chunk) => (encrypted += chunk));
      cipher.on("end", () => {
        console.log(encrypted);
        res.json({ encrypted });
      });
      cipher.write(req.body.payload);
      cipher.end();
    });
  });
});
app.post("/decrypt", (req, res) => {
  const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, "salt", 24);
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let decrypted = "";
  decipher.on("readable", () => {
    while (null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
      decrypted += chunk.toString("utf8");
    }
  });
  decipher.on("end", () => {
    console.log(decrypted);
    res.json({ decrypted });
  });
  decipher.write(req.body.payload, "hex");
  decipher.end();
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? the `password` is read from a `const` in the file, hence incorrect password is not the reason.

Comment: Decryption uses a zero IV and not the random IV applied during encryption. Usually the IV and ciphertext are concatenated during encryption and passed to the decrypting side. Alternatively you can generate the IV together with the key using `scrypt()`.

Comment: Note that a constant salt is insecure. The salt must be randomly generated for each encryption and is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext (usually concatenated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco, this is what I came up with:

```
app.post("/encrypt", (req, res) => {
  crypto.scrypt(password, "salt", 24, (err, key) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let encrypted = "";
    cipher.setEncoding("hex");
    cipher.on("data", (chunk) => (encrypted += chunk));
    cipher.on("end", () => res.json({ encrypted }));
    cipher.write(req.body.payload);
    cipher.end();
  });
});
app.post("/decrypt", (req, res) => {
  const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, "salt", 24);
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let decrypted = "";
  decipher.on("readable", () => {
    while (null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
      decrypted += chunk.toString("utf8");
    }
  });
  decipher.on("end", () => res.json({ decrypted }));
  decipher.write(req.body.payload, "hex");
  decipher.end();
});
```